# storing boolean value

Tags: java, boolean

I have the problem how to change boolean value of a given class so that once it is encountered again it has the value last set.  This is my class

```
public class Sandwich {
    private String type;
    private double price;
    private String ing;
    public boolean owned;

    Sandwich (String t, double p, boolean o){
        type = t;
        price = p;
        owned = o;
    }

    public boolean getO(){
        return this.owned;
    }

    public void setO(boolean o){
        this.owned = o;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

and place where it is accessed and supposed to change:

```
public void purchase(Sandwich s) {
    boolean owned = s.owned;

    //I tried also with accessor and mutator here but then changed to public
    String type = s.getType();
    if (owned == false) {
        if (money <= 0){ 
            System.out.println("Worker " + this.name + " can not buy " + type + " sandwich, cuz he doesn't have enough money");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Worker " + this.name + " can buy " + type + " sandwich");
            this.money = money;
            owned = true;

            //this is the place where it is supposed to change value to true (sandwich was bought and has owner now
            s.owned = owned;
        }
    } else if (owned == true) {
        System.out.println("Worker " + this.name + " can not buy " + type + " sandwich cuz it was bought");
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Problem is that although a given sandwich was bought in the past its owned value is set to false each time I try to run this code.  I need for the sandwich to record changed value of owned so that next time I run the condition will be owned == true.  How can it

Comment: So you need it to persist between the runs of the application? Or when the application is running?

Comment: Please use `if (owned)` and `(!owned)`, noting that in this case performing the opposite of a `!owned` test is redundant, if it's not `!owned`, it will always be `owned`.

Comment: Whatever problem you're having, it has nothing to do with the boolean inside the `Sandwitch` class. If you were to test the functionality on its own you would find that setting it and reading it work correctly. You're doing something in code you're not posting that has `owned` being set to `false`

Comment: Are you mixing the sold sandwiches with the unsold ones and randomly picking one to sell, and checking if it's sold or not? Looks like you are not designing your sandwich shop properly.

Comment: Is there any possibility you're not using the same `Sandwich` instance but a new one?

Comment: We need other code. The problem is not in the code you are showing us. Show us the code where `new Sandwich()` is called.

Comment: There may be a possiblity that this is a new instance indeed Code is in another class Main (one of them) Sandwich Cheese = new Sandwich("Cheese", 3.5, false);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a flaw in your design. You need to create a relationship between the Worker and the sandwish type.

What you can do is simply implement a List of purchased sandwish types in the worker class and compare against it whenever a worker purchases a sandwish.

Or if you want, you can have a hashmap of all sandwish types with a boolean value that indicates whether the type has already been purchased or not.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of sandwich each time you run the code. It is not the same object.

Comment: should this list be created in purchase class or somewhere else in the code? thank you

Comment: It can be in the Worker to define the types purchased by a single worker, if that's what you want

Comment: I tried the thing with the list in the purchase method of the worker class.  I have discovered (checking how many items are inside) that it counts 1, 2 and then restarts (probably once a new worker is created) and once again counts 1,2.  Each time I only purchase 2 sandwiches by 2 workers.  Worker Marty = new Worker("Marty", 5); Worker Biff = new Worker("Biff", 12);  Marty.purchase(Usa); Marty.purchase(Cheese); Biff.purchase(Ham); Biff.purchase(Cheese);

Comment: If you want your list to be shared between all the workers, make it static

Answer (score 2):

You created get and set routines and then didn't use them.  I would change the code to  this.

```
    public void purchase(Sandwich s){
            String type = s.getType();
            if (!(s.getO())){
                if (money <= 0){ 
                    System.out.println("Worker " + this.name + " can not buy " + type + " sandwich, cuz he doesn't have eno

ugh money");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Worker " + this.name + " can buy " + type + " sandwich");
                    this.money = money;
                    s.setO(true);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Worker " + this.name + " can not buy " + type + " sandwich cuz it was bought");
                System.out.println("Test");
            }
     }
```

Comment: While that is proper, it wouldn't change a thing. The problem isn't the class or its `owned` field.

Comment: @Brian Roach - On second thought, you are more likely right.  The problem lies somewhere else.  Forest-trees-ouch!

Comment: I'd still recommend using the setter/getter and make the field itself private. Why have a plain setter and getter for a field that is public anyways? +1 from me :)

Comment: yep it seems problem is somwhere else any ideas.  This is a development version so the field was private than changed to public, etc

Comment: If that is the case, the solution is fairly simple.  Change it back to private and see where the program breaks!  The other thing to do is use a search engine to see everywhere Sandwich.owned or getO() or setO() is used in the entire project.

Comment: as I said I have already tried with private and setter and getter method I posted a different version with a public field and limited use of setter or getter

Comment: I probably didn't explain it well enough.  When you change it back to private one of two things will happen.  

If the code no longer compiles, then the source file & line with the problem are most likely the location that is changing owned.  

If the code still compiles, then another source file is using setO() to change the value.  In this case, you will have to search the entire app to find that location.

Comment: when I changed it back to private code indeed didn't compile then I used setter and getter and it compiled again.  No other source file is using setO().  I think maybe a different object is created each time I run it.  However can't say what is the place it happens.

Comment: Ah, then find where the code creates a new Sandwich (i.e. - something = new Sandwich()).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove

```
boolean owned = s.owned;
```

and use `s.getO()` where you have used `owned`

e.g.

```
if (owned == false){
```

can be

```
if (!s.getO()){
```

And use the setter method `s.setO(true/false)` to change it.

e.g.

```
owned = true;
s.owned = owned;
```

can be replaced by

```
s.setO(true);
```

Comment: While that is proper, it wouldn't change a thing. The problem isn't the class or its `owned` field.

Comment: Correct.  I simply tried different versions (also with getters and setters) but it doesn't work so problem seems to be somewhere elese

Comment: Please follow what people have said and update your post accordingly.